# Can I open Microsoft EDGE through JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, microsoft-edge, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I want to open EDGE browser through JMeter. All other browsers have specific config element present within **JMeter**. But Edge does not have any & I want to use the edge browser.

Answer (score 3):

Currently [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) doesn't support Edge browser, you can reach out to[JMeter Plugins developers and maintainers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) and clarify is the feature on the roadmap and if/when it will be implemented.

In the meantime you can still launch Edge browser from JMeter using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language

1. Make sure to install [JMeter WebDriver plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/). The below instructions assume [Selenium/WebDriver Support plugin version 3.0](https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-webdriver-3.0.zip), it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

   [image]
2. Download [`selenium-edge-driver-3.14.0.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-edge-driver/3.14.0) and store it under "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Download [`MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) for your Edge version and put it under "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
4. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
5. Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan
6. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "../lib/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
   def driver = new org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver()
   driver.get("http://jmeter.apache.org")
   ```
7. That's it, JMeter should kick off Edge browser and open the [JMeter website](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**:
To invoke the EDGE browser through a WebDriver in JMeter follow this steps:

1. Download [Microsoft Edge WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)
2. Install [JMeter-Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
3. Add `jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler` to your test plan
4. Add `jp@gc - Internet Explorer Driver Config` to your test plan
5. Choose `Internet Explorer Driver Config` and open an `Internet Explorer` tab
6. Specify the path to the EDGE WebDriver in the appropriate field
7. Save and Run your test - EDGE browser will be launched!

[image]

**Also you may just simulate EDGE browser without WebDriver**

1. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
2. Add `User-Agent` header with one of [Edge User Agent strings](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/edge/?order_by=-times_seen) to HTTP Header Manager

Some strings for example, chhose nay one to simulate EDGE:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
```

**User-agent strings for Microsoft Edge**

> Microsoft Edge for desktop and mobile in Windows 10 and RemoteIE builds is designed for maximum interoperability with other modern browsers and contemporary web content. The desktop, mobile, and WebView user-agent strings are below.
>
> Desktop:
>
> ```
>  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; <64-bit tags>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Safari/<WebKit Rev> Edge/<EdgeHTML Rev>.<Windows Build>
> ```
>
> Mobile
>
> ```
>  Mozilla/5.0 (WM 10.0; Android <Android Version>; <Device Manufacturer>; <Device Model>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Rev> Edge/<EdgeHTML Rev>.<Windows Build>
> ```

[Microsoft EDGE User-agent string changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh869301(v=vs.85))

Comment: I want to invoke the edge browser through a web driver. So the solution above being correct unfortunately doesn't help my case. Can you please tell me how to invoke the edge browser using WEB DRIVER.

Comment: @AkashMalpure for now you can do it. I updated my answer with the solution.