# Is it possible to use Microsoft Edge in inPrivate mode or with Guest account using a JSR223 Sampler in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, microsoft-edge, jmeter-5.0

Following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514770/10002168), I've been able to run a script to log in to a web app I'm testing on Microsoft Edge using Groovy in a JSR223 Sampler in JMeter. My script clicks on a "Sign In" button, which then automatically signs me in (presumably through my credentials used to sign into my computer*). However, this test case should be able to log in as multiple users, so having me automatically sign in with my credentials isn't the intended use case. Through some trial-and-error, I found that I don't get automatically signed in when using the web app in Edge either (a) with inPrivate mode or (b) with a Guest account. Using either one of these approaches seems the most intuitive way to resolve this issue, but I am not sure if there's a way to do either (or both) of them in JMeter.

*It's a company laptop and I can't log in as a local user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're smart enough to instantiate and start EdgeDriver you should be able to do configure it as well.

[Capabilities and EdgeOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options) article shows available parameters.

For particular you case it would be something like:

```
def options = new EdgeOptions()
options.setCapability("InPrivate", true)
```

or if you prefer a full piece of code to copy and paste:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "../lib/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
def options = new EdgeOptions()
options.setCapability("InPrivate", true)
def driver = new org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver(options)
driver.get("http://jmeter.apache.org")
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

However in general I would rather look into the way of impersonating a different domain user via [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) using i.e. [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy capable of adding relevant headers to the browser controller by the WebDriver

Comment: I tried using the setCapability method to set inPrivate mode to "true" using the following strings, but none of them started Edge in inPrivate mode: "InPrivate", "inPrivate", "inprivate", "Private", "private", "incognito", "Incognito", and "start-in-incognito".

Comment: Following [this Selenium guide](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/driver_idiosyncrasies/driver_specific_capabilities/), I also tried using the addCommandSwitches method, but I got a MissingMethodException. The same thing happened with setCapability, addArguments, and addAdditionalCapability.